# add custom header from browser client to web server (laravel)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, http, http-headers

I tried using ajax setup in jquery to add the custom header for get/post request to laravel. But seem it's not working.

My expected result is add every request with custom header sending to laravel (to get verify by middleware) and only return view if success.

Ajax code:

```
   $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-Token': 'xxxxxx'
      }
    });
```

The middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{

    $token = $request->header('X-Token');

    if(!empty($token)){
      return $next($request);  //token received and continue
    }
    else{
      return ''; // no token received and stop here 
    }
}
```

The view:

```
public function index(){
    return View::make("dashboard")->render(); //if middleware pass, return view
}
```

The web route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'token.verify'], function()
{
    Route::get('/dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
});
```

The view is entire view (not the partial view).

Comment: Have you checked in the developer tools of your browser if the header is actually passed?

Comment: It passed on the first time but when rendered the new view, it not passing (just having cookies value)